# Java Arrays - Different values for the same object

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, slick2d

Using Slick2D I am looping through my buttons and highlighting the one that is currently being hovered over. I do this by saving the index of a button whose `onHover` event fires. However, when I hover over the first button, it highlights the last. Hovering over the second button highlights the second to last, etc. If I use the keyboard to change the selected button it works perfectly, though.

Here is the method to save the index :

```
public void onHover(int x, int y) {
    Button but;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        but = b.get(i);
        if (but.isClicked(x, y)) {
            choice = i;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the one to compare them :

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    Button but;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        but = b.get(i);
        if (i == choice) {
            but.drawHighlighted(g);
        } else {
            but.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a special way to do this?

**EDIT :** *I figured out where the problem was.*

Mouse.getY() from LWJGL (which i use with onHover method) returns the height of the window minus the Y position of the mouse ; while mouseReleased(button, x, y) from Slick2D (which i use with draw method) returns the "true" Y position.
But both returns the same value with the x position.

I still don't know why the values are different (since Slick2D is based on LWJGL), but to bypass the problem, i use now HEIGHT - Mouse.getY() to have the right position.

Thanks everbody for helping me with that problem !

Comment: Hmm, using a foreach loop _and_ `.indexOf()` on the list after that is rather strange; a plain `for` loop here would be more efficient and more readable ;)

Comment: @fge I used a plain for first ; but i had the same problem... So i tried with a for each for testing purposes. I have edited my question with the plain for loops :)

Comment: What sort of collection are your buttons in? Is there any guarantee of order?

Comment: @NathanielFord They are in an ArrayList, i think they are guarantee of order.

Comment: You should debug/log out what indexes are actually being passed to `choice` and `draw`.

Comment: Yes, it is better to write for(Button but:b){}

Comment: @user2097804 in this case, the index in the list is used

Comment: @NathanielFord After a log, i figured out this : Using Slick's method mouseReleased (based in LWJGL) returns the right value, but using directly Mouse.getX() and Mouse.getY() from lwjgl.input seems to return the wrong one...

Comment: That's it, i figured out where was the problem : with a 600 height window, and the mouse at (0,181), Mouse.getY() returns 479 (which is wrong) ; while on mouseReleased(button, x, y), y = 181 (the right value). I still don't know why, but my problem is solved. Thanks everybody ! :)